# Cannot serialize the DataTable. DataTable name is not set. anyone know why?

Tags: c#, web-services

can someone please help me?
I can't find the problem:

```
 string accID = Session["accountid"].ToString();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.TableName = "zubur amak";
dt = service.GetTransactions(accID);
transactions.DataSource = dt;
transactions.DataBind();
```

Comment: Try setting the table name after `dt = service.GetTransactions(accID);`

Comment: try this: DataTable dt = new Datatable("Tablename");

Comment: I tried, it gives me the same error.

Comment: What did you try?